# Boundedness of matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a n by n matrix whose entries are continuous functions of $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Fix a matrix norm $\|\cdot \|$ and assume that $\|A(x^\star)\| < 1$.

Then, the claim is that there exists a closed ball $B$ of radius $r$ centred at $x^\star$ such that there exists a constant $0< C < 1 $ such that for every $x\in B$, $\|A(x)\|\leq C$.

How should I prove it? I do not see how the continuity of the entries of A implies the uniform bound on the matrix norm. I am thinking that the uniform bound on the norm of $A$ must come from the compactness of the ball $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\left\Vert A\left(x^{\star}\right)\right\Vert=K<1$.

For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $r>0$ s.t. $0<\left\Vert x^{\star}-x\right\Vert<r$ implies 
$$\left|\left\Vert A\left(x\right)\right\Vert-\left\Vert A\left(x^{\star}\right)\right\Vert \right|\leq\left\Vert A\left(x\right)-A\left(x^{\star}\right)\right\Vert<\epsilon.$$

If $\left\Vert A\left(x\right)\right\Vert>\left\Vert A\left(x^{\star}\right)\right\Vert$,
then $\left\Vert A\left(x\right)\right\Vert<\left\Vert A\left(x^{\star}\right)\right\Vert+\epsilon<K+\epsilon$.
Since $K<1$, you can pick $K+\epsilon=C<1$.

Edit: for completeness, I should mention that you need to take the closure of the ball above.

Comment: A lot of stuff in the original question is unnecessary. All this is saying is if you have a continuous function that is bounded at a point, you can find a ball around that point in which the function is similarly bounded.

Comment: Why, or I should say, how, is the mapping $x \to \|A(x)\|$ continuous?

Comment: I didn't use that. I used continuity w.r.t. the given norms.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Your question assumes $x\mapsto A(x)$ is continuous. Since you did not mention what topologies this function is continuous w.r.t., I took the only topologies available: those generated by the norms.

Comment: I am not assuming $x \mapsto A(x)$ is continuous. I am assuming that the entries of $A(x)$ are continuous functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27519/discussion-between-par-and-pm021).